# Is it possible to fire event on buttons returned from PHP by API in angular 13?

Tags: php, angular, typescript, api, angular13

I am using Angular Data-table. I returned edit and delete buttons from backend. The buttons are showing on frontend in UI but the click event or any other function is not working on them.
Can anyone guide me through this? Thanks in advance.

I tried all the things available on google but nothing work out.

Comment: You can post some necessary UI code and PHP response to better understand the problem.

Comment: Indeed, can't help you if we can't see what you're working with. Please provide relevant code snippets.